# Load variable data into a workbook using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-csv

I have an API request that set a variable named $data with CSV style data.
I want to open a Workbook with that data without writing on disk.

How can I do that?

The best I can do is

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$workbook.worksheets(1).Cells(1,1) = $csv
```

Unfortunately, it fills my CSV into 1 cell, adding delimiter, instead of simply "copying" data into the workbook.

Comment: Why is it important not to write to disk?

Comment: Give importexcel module a try

Comment: I cannot write to disk. Ideally I wish to 'pipe' the variable content into a CSV and upload it to a sharepoint. The Excel.Application ComObject is the only thing that can easily do that

Comment: If your are having a CSV style data, why not use Import-csv instead of excel application

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple task if you want to use the ComObject, as you can use `ConvertTo-Csv` with a tab delimiter, copy to the clipboard, and paste into Excel. Here's a snippet of what I've used in a script myself to do just that:

```
$tasks|ConvertTo-Csv -del "`t" -NoTypeInformation|clip

$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$XL.Visible = $true
$WB = $XL.Workbooks.Add()
$XL.ActiveCell.PasteSpecial() | Out-Null
```